# Get frame of item when dragging from UICollectionView

Tags: uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, ios11

I want to drag items from a UICollectionView onto a custom UIView. However, when I'm dropping, I want to know the point that the item was dragged at, so I can calculate the exact place where to draw the new item(, so it doesn't "jump" to slightly different coordinates when the user lifts his finger).

How can I get the frame of the dragged item?

Comment: I faced the same issue. Solution that worked for me can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61308512/13030733)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidropinteractiondelegate/2890870-dropinteraction The default preview gives us a point with `defaultPreview.target.center`.